# yum or apt-get does not work on amazon-aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, yum

when I do `yum`,
it says

```
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

my aws instance details are as given below:

```
Linux ip-72-311-15-127 3.14.27-25.47.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 18:36:15 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`/usr/bin/apt-get` also not available

`/usr/bin/yum` is there so I tried

```
/usr/bin/yum install -u mongodb-org
```

which gives

```
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion for this?

Comment: What operating system did you install?

Comment: Looks like Amazon broke their distribution again. You should avoid Amazon Linux whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have a broken Python install. You should probably just create a new instance, and don't waste your time trying to fix this.

Also, `apt-get` is used on Debian and Ubuntu systems, and `yum` is used on Redhat, CentOS, and AWS Linux systems. You should make sure that you're using the correct tool for your OS.

Comment: Saw this problem when python3 is installed and it replaces the /usr/bin/python link